# MySQL - SubQuery - Error in your SQL Syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm pretty new to SQL, so I'll try to keep it simple as to what I'm trying to do.

I have a system which I'm looking to select messages from, starting with the most recent first, select a maximum of 5 pieces of data, then after that resort them with the latest 'time' column last in order for them to display properly.

Here's the syntax I'm using:

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE sender = '$uid' AND reciever = '$new_user_id' 
OR reciever = '$uid' AND sender = '$new_user_id' ORDER BY id ASC 
FROM (SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY time DESC)
```

And here's the error that I'm getting:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'FROM (SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY time DESC)' at line 1

I understand that I'm getting something wrong here, but as SQL isn't really my thing, I haven't a clue where to turn.

A little help would go to great causes, I've been banging my head on the wall for hours.

Thanks.

Comment: maybe because you are defining `FROM` twice?

Comment: Just edited it apparently I seem to of missed out a ORDER BY before the second FROM.

Comment: You still are using two `FROM` statements. Try to break the query into sub-parts(as I have done in my answer) it helps you know the logic better. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM messages 
    WHERE
    (sender = '$uid' AND reciever = '$new_user_id')
    OR (reciever = '$uid' AND sender = '$new_user_id')
    ORDER BY time asc
    LIMIT 5) AS a ORDER by a.time DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 5)
  WHERE ( sender = '$uid' 
    AND reciever = '$new_user_id' )
    OR ( reciever = '$uid' 
    AND sender = '$new_user_id' )
  ORDER BY time ASC;
```

**EDIT** Edited to resort with ascending time values in last 5 items inserted.

Comment: Could you check out the query again, sorry I made a mistake in the first one as I had two versions of the query.

Comment: Thanks, this should help me get it sorted!

Answer (score 0):

No need for the subquery it seems.  Take off the subquery and tack on ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 5.

Comment: Could you check out the query again, sorry I made a mistake in the first one as I had two versions of the query.